# The internet speed dropped down when i upgraded to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, internet, vaio

I upgraded my VAIO VGN-CR35G to 11.10 and it was all fine until i opened an internet browser to come to a complete halt when trying to load Google. Strangely it's only me and everyone else in the house doesn't have such an issue. (we have Windows, Linux and Mac running so it's just me). What can i do?

Comment: whats happening if you ping any site from terminal ?